# How to use OR operation in Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$xml.selectnodes('/POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER/MAPPING/TRANSFORMATION/TRANSFORMFIELD[@NAME="f_DISB_ST_CHG_DT" OR @NAME="fS_DISB_ST_CHG_NULL"]')
```

This is my code. I want to select attributes @name with value "ES_DISB_ST_CHG_NULL" or "S_DISB_ST_CHG_DT" but its not working.Can someone explain what am i doing wrong?.

Comment: `or` needs to be lowercase.

Comment: WOW!.. i'm so stupid.. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "OR" with 'or'